# Laravel 5.5 - Send Email - Can't Get Property On Non-Object

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send email from a Laravel 5.5 controller like this...

```
    $user = User::find(1)->toArray();
    Mail::send('emails.invite', $user, function($message) use ($user) {
        $message->to($user->email);
        $message->from('me@example.com');
        $message->subject('Test Subject');
    });
```

This fails with the error...

```
"message": "Trying to get property of non-object",
```

If I echo the array into the subject I can see that I do have the correct $user available to me, but for some reason it doesn't like it when I try and extract $user->email

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$user` is type of`array` not `object` as you expected, because of  `toArray()` called on returned model. Either change that line and remove said `toArray()` to keep it unchanged object, or make this line:

```
$message->to($user->email);
```

look more like:

```
$message->to($user['email']);
```

with proper array element reference.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `->toArray()` on the `User` object and so it is no longer an object!

```
$user = User::find(1); // Assuming you are already protecting yourself from potentially not finding a user
$viewData = $user->toArray(); // Or better still don't expose the underlying structure
Mail::send('emails.invite', $viewData, function($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to($user->email);
    $message->from('me@example.com');
    $message->subject('Test Subject');
});
```

Comment: That looks like it should work but gives me ... "Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given,

Comment: `Mail::send('emails.invite', $user->toArray()`

Comment: The data is expected to be an array.